# Octopress pushing error to GitHub

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I'm trying to push an octopress to github page,everything has worked fine up to now but when i do the rake deploy command after displaying octopress files i get the following error

```
To git@github.com:rukshn/rukshn.github.io.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:rukshn/rukshn.github.io.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

what's the problem?

Comment: @SLaks what's the problem and how to fix it

Comment: Looking at the Octopress Rakefile, it should pull any changes before pushing but it would appear that this hasn't happened. Have you tried running `git pull` first, as the error message suggests?

Comment: did pull then again did the 'rake deploy' and still gets the same error so i did pull again which then showed everything is uptodate

Comment: I just delete the `master` branch, and then `rake deploy` again

Answer (score 31):

Since this is the master branch, i.e., the one running your generated pages, you need to drop into the `_deploy` directory, then do the `git pull origin master`. Somehow your deploy directory has gotten out of sync. Do you have more than one local repo you write to and deploy from? (Say on different machines...) If you do, then you should always make sure to sync your the sources on the various repos as well.

Comment: this should be marked as the answer. not sure how I managed to muck up the master branch but this fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I would delete _deploy, clone my repo(master branch) to _deploy directory, and run rake commands again. I had to do that because started to edit my blog from different computrer

Answer (score 13):

do

```
cd _deploy
git reset --hard origin/master
cd ..
```

and try again

```
rake generate
rake deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`git checkout source`

`rake gen_deploy`

Comment: still get the same error message and the octopress is not pushed to github

Answer (score 0):

- [@slavik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3726554/slavik) comment works **like a charm.**
- [@Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581442/benjamin-tan) I think [@rksh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1601443/rksh) skipped below steps,

**Don't forget** to commit the source for your blog.

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m 'add source code to source branch'`
3. `git push origin source`

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem and solved it by removing the master branch in the _deploy folder in the source branch. The detailed commands are as follows:

```
// change directory to _deploy
cd _deploy                             

// check out local master branch
git checkout master                    

// rename local master to master2
git branch -m master2                  

// list of remote branch
git branch -r                          

// create a new local master branch and tracking remote master branch
git checkout origin/master -b master   

// pull the remote master branch, ensure that the local master branch has Already up-to-date.
git pull                               

// delete the local master2 branch if not needed.
git branch -d master2
```

```